# Prefilling a form with a URL

Tags: forms, url, web, fill

I'm a newbie, so this solution to my problem may be obvious or there may be no way to do this. Anyway, here it is: I have an application form that people fill out, and I need to make a url that when somebody goes to the url, the referral field is already filled out with my name.

This is the application: http://cataclysmgamingcxg.enjin.com/application

And I am trying to make the field below "Who recruited you? Be as close as possible when you give us their gamertag" to be filled out with "Gamertag23Gamer".

If somebody can teach me how to do this, or even make such a url for me, that would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using on your backend? You could pass the gamertag in as a parameter in the URL  http://cataclysmgamingcxg.enjin.com/application?gametag=gamer12 and then return the pre-filled information when the page is sent to the client. You could always use Javascript, as mentioned in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter

Comment: I don't know; it's not my website. It's hosted on enjin.com, if that helps. Again, I'm a newbie and I don't know much about this sort of stuff. I read somewhere that you can put the gamertag in as a parameter in the URL, but I haven't found a way to do that in this specific case. Do you have to find out what that specific field is called?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work unless that site is set up to allow you to do that. Unless you know that other people have done it with this particular site, you're probably out of luck.